# e4x vs XPath: Which one to use when going with action script programming in Flex?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xpath, flex3, e4x

e4x programming extension is native to Actionscript and makes sense to use it over Xpath or any other DOM interfaces. I would like to know 
from flex community if they had any bad experiences like performance, etc, or any other gotchas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e4x has been a godsend in many of my applications. It's easy to use and I have seen no performance issues. I have gotten so spoiled by e4x I've started using XML instead of ArrayCollections more than I should.

In my opinion e4x is the way to go.